# how to use ROS2 in raspberry5 ？

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

Raspberry5  only  support  ubuntu23.10+.
Ros2  only  support ubuntu22.04-.

So,how to use  raspberry5  ？

Answer (score 1):

As you said, Raspberry pi 5 supports only the version of ubuntu 23+.

It would be reasonable to use a virtual environment such as docker to run ROS2 in that environment.

Alternatively, the ROS2 Humble could be used through the following procedure.

https://lkseng.github.io/posts/2024/01/07/ros-2-humble-on-raspberrypi-5.html

Answer (score 0):

If you using Raspberry Pi OS (Bookworm) arm64, and do not need custom modification of ROS 2, you might want to check https://github.com/Ar-Ray-code/rpi-bullseye-ros2 for ROS 2 Iron, it's very easy to set up and install.